# Why pointers to the same object have different values?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I've this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() : m_i(0) { }
protected:
    int m_i;
};
class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }
protected:
    double m_d;
};
class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') { }
private:
    char m_c;
};

int main()
{
    C d;
    A *b1 = &d;
    B *b2 = &d;

    std::cout << (long)b1 << std::endl <<(long)b2<< std::endl;
}
```

when compiled and run it produces the following output:

```
140734705182320
140734705182328
```

It is not completely clear why different pointers to the same address (&d) have different values.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Because they *don't* point to the same object. `b1` points an `A` object, `b2` points to a `B` object. Neither class is a subtype of the other, so neither can point to a subobject of the other.

Comment: The pointers do have different addresses, but that is not what your program is demonstrating. It is demonstrating that they *store* different addresses.

Comment: You should convert the pointer values to `void*`, not `long`, for printing.

Comment: And use a static_cast, not a C-style one.

Answer (score 12):

The memory layout of a `C` object will be something like:

```
A base_object_1;
B base_object_2;
char m_c;
```

The two base objects have different addresses; `A` will (typically) have the same address as the full object, but `B` will (typically) not. Certainly they can't have the same address as each other, unless at least one is empty.

So converting a pointer to the full object into a pointer to one of the base objects must change the pointer value in order to point to the correct address.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that `C* b3 = &d;` will point to the same address as `b1`. And just to be completely clear: if you change the example so that `B` inherits from `A` (and `C` only directly inherits from `B`) then `b1`, `b2` and `b3` have the same value.

Comment: @CompuChip: Indeed; although neither of those is guaranteed by the language.

Comment: Exactly, and neither should you have to care. The reason you are using an `A`-pointer to a `C`-instance is that you can access the `A`-interface to it without knowing its runtime type - not that you can to pointer magic (aka arithmetic) on it :)